# Binding ContextMenu in DataTemplate

Tags: .net, binding, tags, contextmenu, datatemplate

I have:

```
 <ListBox>
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:StyleViewModel}">
                    <DockPanel>                            
                        <Button Content="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}">
                            <Button.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.RemoveMember1FavoriteStyleCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </Button.ContextMenu>
                        </Button>                            
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to bind the command in the menuitem of the context menu to an ICommand that is defined in a viewmodel that is the datacontext of the listbox, and the commandparameter should be the StyleViewModel, but what I tried didn't work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveCustomer.Member1FavoriteStyles}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ListBoxStyleItemsPanelAsVerticalStackPanel}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemContainerStyle}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:StyleViewModel}">
                    <DockPanel>                            
                        <Button Content="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}">
                            <Button.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Remove" Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.RemoveMember1FavoriteStyleCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </Button.ContextMenu>
                        </Button>                            
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost working now, except that now CommandParameter="{Binding}" is not returning the StyleViewModel:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveCustomer.Member1FavoriteStyles}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ListBoxStyleItemsPanelAsVerticalStackPanel}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemContainerStyle}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:StyleViewModel}">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Button Content="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}">
                            <Button.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.Tag}">
                                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding ActiveCustomer.Member1FirstName}" Command="{Binding RemoveMember1FavoriteStyleCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </Button.ContextMenu>
                        </Button>                            
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
```

I'm wondering if it can be done...